# React: Sharing singleton data with multiple components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, singleton

I am writing a React Component in a library that allows its multiple instances to share state, update state and track when all of its instances are unmounted.

Since its a library, I cannot use `Context` provider pattern because I cannot wrap the client's root App with the `Provider`.

I wrote the following singleton API and a custom hook that solves my problem, but is it safe?
Are there any corner cases that might cause problem with my approach?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
let counter = 0;
const listeners = [];

const notifyAll = () => listeners.forEach((cb) => cb(counter));

const counterApi = {
  current: () => counter,
  register: (cb) => listeners.push(cb),
  increment: () => {
    counter += 1;
    notifyAll();
  },
  exit: (cb) => {
    const index = listeners.findIndex((listener) => listener === cb);
    if (index !== -1) {
      listeners.splice(index, 1);
      if (listeners.length === 0) {
        console.log("all components using the counter have been unmounted");
      }
    }
  }
};

export function useCounter() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(counterApi.current());
  useEffect(() => {
    counterApi.register(setValue);
    return () => {
      counterApi.exit(setValue);
    };
  }, []);
  return [value, counterApi.increment];
}
```

Comment: You don't wrap the client's root node in a Context provider, you return a Context provider component and the client wraps their root node with it. Don't use unrestricted globals in React and Javascript in general.

Comment: But how would I track if all instances of my component have been unmounted? I need to mix this singleton api with React, or is there any other way?

Comment: Also, with Context API, I ask clients to do additional stuff while in my singleton approach, I can use the hook in my component and then export it. Client usage is seamless.

Comment: The `useEffect` hook's callback can return a cleanup function to clean up any active subscriptions. Use this to "inform" your Context a component has unmounted or otherwise disconnected. The only additional piece to this is your code providing the Context provider component, the custom hook handles the rest inside each component using it. It's just the more correct React way to manage this. Your clients hopefully are familiar enough with React to understand needing to wrap their app code with your provider, especially if you've documented it.

Comment: React Contexts are nothing new in React. In a way it sort of seems you've implemented a simple state management using a Pub/Sub pattern... almost what Redux is in React.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Out of curiosity, anything wrong or broken with my singleton suggestion?

Comment: Nothing overtly obvious, but when you manage "state" outside the React component lifecycle sometimes things can get a little weird and "out of sync".

Comment: I've used this pattern before and it works great. You do have to worry about dirty updates, but since you're exposing the increment function directly, which closes over the module state, there's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I see with this is that it's just about the ***least*** React way to accomplish a single global state value. Instead of any single React state you instantiate a duplicate `value` state for each instance usage of the `useCounter` hook and then have implemented a lot of additional logic round adding and removing subscribers to keep everything synchronized.

**Make React work *for* you, don't work *against* React.** When you start using "state" and other values *outside* the React component lifecycle it leads to code you are trying to use where you need track everything manually and can lead to state/render synchronicity issues if not implemented/maintained properly.

Use a React Context to hold a single `count` state and expose out the state and an increment callback via the `useCounter` hook. React will manage the "subscriptions" to the Context simply by being mounted or not.

Example:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

export const CounterContext = createContext([0, () => {}]);

const CounterProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  const increment = () => setValue((value) => value + 1);

  return (
    <CounterContext.Provider value={[value, increment]}>
      {children}
    </CounterContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useCounter = () => useContext(CounterContext);

export default CounterProvider;
```

Import and wrap the app code with the `CounterProvider`.

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import CounterProvider from "./CounterApi";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <CounterProvider>
      <App />
    </CounterProvider>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Consumers use the `useCounter` hook as per normal.

```
import { useCounter } from './CounterApi';

const Component = ({ name }) => {
  const [count, increment] = useCounter();

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Component: {name}</h1>
      <div>Count: {count}</div>
      <button type="button" onClick={increment}>+</button>
    </>
  )
};
```

...

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Component name="First Child" />
      <Component name="Second Child" />
      <Component name="Third Child" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-sharing-singleton-data-with-multiple-components]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I got this from the comments. However, context doesn’t have a callback hook for when no subscriptions are active. For that the useCounter hook will have to return another function that can be used by components in useEffect and its cleanup to signal mount and unmount. Then the provider will have to run an effect for whenever 0 listeners are reached.

Comment: @rachitiitr I see. Yeah, that makes sense and would be my suggestion.